# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError but can successfully connect using mongodbCompass

Tags: python-3.x, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb server setup which I access remotely. I have the server I think correctly set up for remote connections (proven by the fact I can connect using mongodbCompass) and a ufw firewall which allows my IP to connect through port 27017, again confirmed this works.

In python I can connect using `MongoClient(connection_string)` without any errors, however when I perform an aggregation I get the timeout error. Running the same aggregation using mongodbCompass works successfully in about half a second (according to explain anyway).

So I am confused why python is timing out and yet mongodbCompass works perfectly

Comment: Perhaps if you showed with `pymongo` how you connect (redacted if necessary) and try your aggregation along with the full error message(s), it would be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: I am facing the same situation when trying to connect using pymongo in my WSL. Strangely, I am able to connect when I run the same script on Windows. This is probably a firewall issue that I haven't been able to figure out yet